# Value in Graph Explorer for subscription is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

i'm following a tutorial to make a susbcription in microsoft graph, but when i want to see my subscription in Graph Explorer, it does not show my subcription, i use GET and https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/ to see but the value is still []. Does anyone knows if i'm doing the right subscription?
This is the query i get when i run query

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions",
    "value": []
}
```

Comment: Point the tutorial you are following. I created a subscription and was able to get that using Graph Explorer. Try creating a subscription from this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example) using Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue when I missed to send as POST request and used GET instead (Postman).
Make sure it is a POST request.